# Ionic 6 - How to read USB Serial content via capacitor/cordova?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, capacitor, capacitor-plugin

I am developing an application using Ionic 6 and Angular. I would like to have the capability to read from a USB device on an Android device, similar to what was possible with the plugin (https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/serial/), but it is no longer functional due to an package issues.

I tried to install an blank project with you know the command 'ionic start  --cordova' but didnt worked too

Answer (score 0):

There is for example:

https://github.com/asad-96/capacitor-plugin-usb-serial

It does not look like it is still maintained.
I forked it and bumped the versions

https://github.com/CoooWeee/capacitor-plugin-usb-serial

It does work for me with <= Android 12 fine. With 13 not all data types work for me. I haven't looked into why, yet.

Comment: thanks for your answer ! But how i can install ur own package ^^?

Comment: just use the repo name e.g. `npm i https://github.com/CoooWeee/capacitor-plugin-usb-serial`